# *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated even when i enter much less chars

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{

    char x[6];
    scanf("%S",x);
    printf("%S",x);
return 0;

}
```

The code is so simple and the output:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
```

Even when I enter just one character, I know about the canary protection variable.

But does the compiler add that variable to my array or there is something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `%s` format specifier, not `%S`. And notice that a correct
prototype for `main` is `int main(void)`. Your code should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char x[6];
  scanf("%s",x);
  printf("%s\n",x);
  return 0;
}
```

Use:

```
$ ./main
abc
abc
```